# How to do sectioning on power bi report

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reporting, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to design a report like this: [image: Mockup Image URL]

I have all the columns in power bi as table.  I dont know how I can get this design.  Can anyone please suggest this.

Comment: Just a general comment: Power BI is frequently misconstrued as a paginated reporting tool. It's not. You'd either need to find a custom visualisation that does what you want, or you need to use pagniated reports

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to design something exactly as shown in the picture then, I'm afraid that it's not possible, and even if you perform some turns and twists then, the visual might not respect the filters.

I would suggest designing such kinds of tables, either prefer excel or, Power BI Report Server.

But, if the design is not primary concern then, you can easily make tables with matrix visual (Just need to play more on the formatting side).